# Opening a new tree view drom dropdow list in odoo

Tags: odoo

I am facing new issue as per as requirement . 
I need to open a new tree view where students list appear by clicking dropdown list with "more" option

Answer (score 0):

Take an example

> in model.py

```
student_ids = fields.Many2many('student.student',string='Student')
```

> in view.xml

```
<field name="student_ids" widget="many2many_tags" />
```

then the field will show a search more in drop down and a tree view when it clicked.